# Django Model and Template Connection

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
{% extends "blogapp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    {% for project in projects %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'sampleimg.jpg' %}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url project.detail %}">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    #image = models.FilePathField(path='/images')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'project':projects
    }
    return render(request,'blogapp/project_index.html',context)

def project_detail(request,pk):
    projects = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'project':projects
    }
    return render(request,'blogapp/project_detail.html',context)
```

I added 2 post from admin but i cant see when i run the server. Here is a ss :

[image: ScreenShot]

I have 2 blog post but i dont see them. What can be the problem?

Comment: Typo in project index view: `'project':projects` -> `'projects':projects`

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake in passing context.
you are using key **project** in context.But you refer **projects** in for loop at **project_index.html**. change key name at view **project** to **projects**.
Not change in any file

> change in passing context dictionary key at project_index view method following

```
def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'projects':projects # here change 'project' to projects in dict key
    }
    return render(request,'blogapp/project_index.html',context)
```

if this stuff work then let me know....

Answer (score 1):

your key name is project, not projects.write this code in your html file :

```
{% for p in project %}
```